# Fabric - Failed to execute task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, twitter-fabric

Today i'd added a new library on my project: https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro
then, Fabric returned an the following error

> E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
>                                                                                     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>                                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
>                                                                                         at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
>                                                                                         at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:235)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
>   11-18 12:50:18.966 13102-13102/it..where E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: it....here, PID: 13102
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it...re/it....re.AndroidExplorer}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=630261345
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:949)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:744)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=630261345
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap.setValueAt(SimpleArrayMap.java:353)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:589)
>                                                                                        at it....anywhere.AndroidExplorer.onStart(AndroidExplorer.java:389)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5991)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2279)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:949) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:744)

That's my gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}



repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':mupdf')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':actionsContentViewLib')
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev244-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile project(':library')

    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
}

android {


    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'p...re'
            keyPassword 'a...s'
            storeFile file('../keystore/release/P..e')
            storePassword 'a....s'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
        targetSdkVersion 23


        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        //debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        //release.setRoot('build-types/release')

    }
    buildTypes {
        NewBuild {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
        }
        release {
//            debuggable true
//            shrinkResources true
//            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
//                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

How i can resolve it?

Comment: make sure you have downloading access

Comment: Post your FragmentActivity `onStart` method. The log is telling you that you are going out of bounds in an array right there

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez 

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

Comment: @Sridhar i've 
 - INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
 - INTERNET
 - READ_PHONE_STATE
 - READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 - MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS
 - ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
 - RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
 - SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 - READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
 - WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
 - INSTALL_SHORTCUT
 - UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
 - WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 - GET_ACCOUNTS
 - DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION
 - ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER
 - STORAGE